Update: Typescript Utility Function Merge Object Key Path
Ok, I appreciate the comments so far, let me reframe the question more specifically.
I have the following setup:
type AbstractIntlMessages = {
    [id: string]: AbstractIntlMessages | string;
};

interface Translations<Locales extends string, Messages extends AbstractIntlMessages = AbstractIntlMessages> {
  Messages: Record<Locales, () => Promise<{ default: Messages }>>;
}

async function combineTranslations<
  Locales extends string,
  Messages extends AbstractIntlMessages = AbstractIntlMessages
>(locale: Locales, definitions: Array<Translations<Locales>>): Promise<Messages> {
  const imported = await Promise.all(definitions.map((definition) => definition.Messages[locale]()));
  const translations = imported.map((t) => t.default);
  return Object.assign({}, ...translations);
}

const SiteTranslations = {
  Messages: {
    en_US: () => Promise.resolve({ default: { Site: { title: 'My Site' } } }),
    es_US: () => Promise.resolve({ default: { Site: { title: 'Mi Sitio' } } }),
  }
};

const AuthFeatureTranslations = {
  Messages: {
    en_US: () => Promise.resolve({ default: { Auth: { title: 'My Auth' } } }),
    es_US: () => Promise.resolve({ default: { Auth: { title: 'Mi Autentico' } } }),
  }
};

const locales = ['en_US', 'es_US'] as const;
type Locales = (typeof locales)[number];

async function i18n(locale: Locales) {
  const messages = await combineTranslations(locale, [
    SiteTranslations,
    AuthFeatureTranslations
  ]);

  console.log(messages)
}

i18n('en_US')

After running combineTranslations the type of messages is AbstractIntlMessages.
How do I structure the types of combineTranslations such that the type of messages is:
{
  Site: {
    title: string;
  };
  Auth: {
    title: string;
  };
}

I am using next-intl which uses the types of messages to drive auto-complete and type validation during dev. Right now that is not working because the type of messages is AbstractIntlMessages.
I'll also note, it does not matter if the attributes of messages are readonly or not. Additionally, the leaf attributes of messages can either be string or their actual string values from the translations.
Here is a link to a TS Playground with the code: https://tsplay.dev/w8qj4N

There's no question in your post. When you tried to implement combineTranslations what problems did you encounter? Are you having trouble with the implementation or the typing? Please [edit] your post to include that implementation and a description of what those problems are. You'll get much better help here if you show a good faith effort to come with the solution yourself, and then we can help you get the rest of way from where you are.

@AlexWayne - Sorry, thank you, updated

Are you asking for the implementation or the typings or both? Like, this approach is how I might do the implementation and the typings, but the work done for those are essentially separate; there's no way for TS to "see" the connection between them. So you need to write out your type functions and write your runtime algorithm separately. Anyway, does this approach meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining (but please do [edit] to be clear whether this is primarily about types or algorithms); if not, what am I missing?

Please consider making this a [mre] that doesn't import from json files we don't have direct access to and doesn't have top-level await or typos like combinePlatformTranslations vs combineTranslations. Ideally we can copy and paste the code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work without having to fix things. It's unfortunate that your example code seems to be more dependent on third-party things like whatever next-intl is, presumably that means we need to know about it in order to venture an answer. Does this approach come close?

Thank you for helping me clarify my thought process, this has been really helpful. I've updated the question above and have updated the approach to demonstrate the last piece.

No, wait… you put my suggestion directly in your question? Including Awaited<ReturnType etc? That’s not how this is supposed to work; you can certainly clarify and refine the question but you shouldn’t be changing it to a followup question by incorporating suggested answers. Please revert the code change to the extent that it’s directly using part of a potential solution.

Apologies, was trying to make it easy. Reverted / updated, hopefully it is all clear (and as a good reference for future)

So, does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Amazing, yes! Thank you! I've been staring at that approach for a bit now and cannot make any sense of it. Any resources you'd recommend outside of the TS docs? Lastly, Go Pack Go!

You could give combineTranslations() the following call signature:
async function combineTranslations<
    L extends Locales,
    const M extends AbstractIntlMessages[]
>(
    locale: L,
    definitions: { [I in keyof M]: Translations<L, M[I]> }
): Promise<{ [I in keyof M]: (x: M[I]) => void } extends
    { [k: number]: (x: infer U) => void } ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] } : never
> {
    const imported = await Promise.all(definitions.map(
      (definition) => definition.Messages[locale]()));
    const translations = imported.map((t) => t.default);
    return Object.assign({}, ...translations);
}

That's generic in two type parameters: L, corresponding to the type of the locale parameter; and M, corresponding to the array of AbstractIntlMessages subtypes relevant for the array of definition.  So if you call combineTranslations("en_US", [SiteTranslations, AuthFeatureTranslations]), we expect L to be "en_US" and M to be [{ Site: { title: string }}, { Auth: { title: string }}].
Note that the type of definitions isn't directly M, but a homomorphic mapped array/tuple type over M (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?) of the form { [I in keyof M]: Translations<L, M[I]> }.  That means, for each element at numeric-like index I of the M array (of the indexed access type M[I]), the corresponding element of the definitions array will be of type Translations<L, M[I]>.  TypeScript can infer from homomorphic mapped types, so the intent is that M will be inferrable from definitions.
Oh, and note that M is a const type parameter to hint to the compiler that we'd like M to be inferred as a tuple instead of as an unordered array.
Once we have L and M, then the return type is Promise<{ [I in keyof M]: (x: M[I]) => void } extends { [k: number]: (x: infer U) => void } ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] } : never> which is essentially Promise<TupleToIntersection<M>>, where TupleToIntersection is a hypothetical utility type that takes a tuple like [X, Y, Z] and converts it into an intersection like X & Y & Z. It uses a technique similar to that shown in Transform union type to intersection type. So if M is [{ Site: { title: string }}, { Auth: { title: string }}], then the output type should be Promise<{ Site: { title: string }} & { Auth: { title: string }}> which is equivalent to the desired Promise<{ Site: { title: string }; Auth: { title: string }}> type where the intersection has been "flattened" into a single object type.  In case it matters, the inferred U type is the intersection of the elements of M, and the mapped type { [P in keyof U]: U[P] } is the "flattened" version of U.

Okay, let's test it out:
const messages = await combineTranslations(locale, [
    SiteTranslations,
    AuthFeatureTranslations
]);
/* function combineTranslations<
     "en_US" | "es_US", 
     [{ Site: { title: string; };}, { Auth: { title: string; };}]
   > */
messages.Auth.title.toUpperCase();
messages.Site.title.toLowerCase();

Looks good. The type of messages is the desired { Site: { title: string }, Auth: { title: string }}.
Playground link to code

Honestly, wow, thank you. Will take some time to digest, but amazing!
